# Scaling an ImageMorph in Smalltalk (Pharo)

Tags: image, scaling, smalltalk, pharo

I am searching for a way to scale an Image Morph in Pharo.
This is what I've tried so far, it did not result in an error, but the Image was the original size:

```
initialize 
| pL pR size pSize |

size := 300.
pSize := size / 12.

super initialize .
self image: (ImageReadWriter formFromFileNamed: 'face.png').
self position: 100@100.
self resize: 100@100.
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to resize an image is to use the `scaledToSize:` method from the `Form` class.

```
imageForm := ZnEasy getPng: 'https://pharo.org/web/files/pharo.png'.
imageForm scaledToSize: 100@30.
```

If you need to have more customized strategies for resizing you can wrap the image form in a `AlphaImageMorph`. For example, in the example below the image is extended to fit the size of the window:

```
(AlphaImageMorph withForm:(ZnEasy getPng: 'https://pharo.org/web/files/pharo.png'))
   layout: #scaledAspect;
   openInWindow.
```